# Kohana, передача в view массива(ов), как более правильно

Tags: php, kohana

У меня есть таблица новостей (1 табл.), к каждой новости привязано несколько картинок (2-ая табл.), есть соответстующие модели.
В контроллере я получаю список новостей:

```
$news = ORM::factory('newsarchive')->find_all()->as_array();
```

Также можно получить картинки для каждой новости:

```
foreach ($news as $n)
    {
        $photos = $n->photos->find_all();
…
```

**Вопрос**:  Мне обязательно в контроллере делать отдельный ассоциативный массив с картинками, чтобы в view отобразить список новостей с картинками, или можно каким-то образом (в *view*) обойтись одним массивом news?
Если можно с одним массивом, то как это будет выглядеть в *view*?

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте отдельные View для вывода картинок и для вывода новости и передайте вид с картинками в вид новости в качестве аргумента:

```
$photos = View::factory('photos');
$new = View::factory('new');
$new->photos = $photos;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ на вопрос:* не обязательно.

Можно упаковать фотки в массив news например по ключу 'photos' както так:

```
$news = array_map(function($newsone) use ($photos){

        $newsone_id = $newsone['id'];

        $newsone['photos'] = array_filter($photos, function($photo) use ($newsone_id) {
            return ($photo['news_id'] == $newsone_id);
        });

        return $newsone;
    }, $news);

$view->news = $news;
```

и во вьюхе получить так:

```
echo Debug::vars( $news['photos'] );
```

*Комментарий:*

Смущает в вашем вопросе другое. Вы для каждой новости будуте делать отдельный запрос. Т.е. 20 новостей - 20 запросов, это плохо с точки зрения производительности. Плюс в контроллере лучше никакую логику не писать, а все писать в модели. Там и добавить к выводу каждой новости, фотографии.

Я бы делал както так:

в модели newsarchive

```
private $with_photos = FALSE;


public function with_photos() {
    $this->with_photos = TRUE;
    return $this;
}

public function find_all_with_photos {

    $news = $this->find_all();

    $news_ids = array_map('id', $news);

    $photos =  ORM::factory('photos')
                    ->where('news.id','IN', (count($news_ids)) ? $news_ids : array(0) )
                    ->find_all()
                    ->as_array();

    $news = array_map(function($newsone) use ($photos){

        $newsone_id = $newsone['id'];

        $newsone['photos'] = array_filter($photos, function($photo) use ($newsone_id) {
            return ($photo['news_id'] == $newsone_id);
        });

        return $newsone;
    }, $news);

    return $news;
}

public function find_all() {

    if ($this->with_photos) {
        return $this->find_all_with_photos();
    }

    return $this->find_all();
}

?>
```

в контроллере

```
<?php

$news = ORM::factory('newsarchive')
                ->with_photos()
                ->find_all();

$view->news = $news;

?>
```

во вьюхе

```
<?php 

echo Debug::vars($news['photos']);

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

вывод новостей с фотографиями

```
<?php foreach ($news as $newsone): ?>

    <?php Debug::vars($newsone); ?>

    <?php foreach ($newsone['photos'] as $photo): ?>

       <?php Debug::vars($photo); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Almaz V. @. Конечно я все новости получаю одним запросом. А в *view*, с помощью *foreach* вывожу каждую новость по отдельности. Просто вопрос был как в *view* при переборе каждой новости, перебирать/выводить все фото к каждой из новостей

Comment: Просто вы привели как пример photos = $n->photos->find_all();. А это как раз то о чем я писал. 20 запросов к фоткам по 20 новостям. Обновил ответ на ваш вопрос: два вложенных цикла.

Comment: Almaz V. @. Там, в моделе на  строке *public function find_all_with_photos (){* ошибка *Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting! * - в чем может быть проблема?...

Comment: пытался менять значения в "xdebug.max_nesting_level", (по умолчанию параметр был закоментирован), так значение *256* (при обновлении странички), просто изменяется на выставленное в "*xdebug.max_nesting_level*" в "php.ini"